# Two target groups behind a NLB both need TLS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, nlb, aws-fargate

I have an ECS cluster with two Fargate services running (frontend and backend).

These services are on two different target groups behind a Network Load Balancer, that redirect TCP 80 to the frontend target group and TCP 8080 to the backend target group.

I've got a certificate for my domain through AWS Certificate Manager and I created a new listener for TLS 443 that forwards request to the frontend target group.

How can I "include" the backend target group in the "TLS"? I've tried to put both services in the same target group but it still redirects to only one of them.

Current situation:

- NLB listener on 443 redirects to -> frontend target group (port 80), works ok
- NLB listener on 8080 redirects to -> backend target group (port 8080), obviously works only in HTTP

How do I add the certificate to the backend?

Comment: Why would you need tls on the backend? This is rarely done and can't be obtained using ACM.

Comment: Because my customer is using SAML for auth, which will do all sorts of redirects through the backend on some endpoints and if the backend doesn't have https the browser will throw errors

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, what I wanted to do is not possible.

I avoided the issue merging frontend and backend in one task and setting up the NLB listener to forward 443 requests to this single task.